# how to parse json list from rest call using generic type?

Tags: java, json, rest

I am trying to parse below json:

```
{
  "00:00:08:00:27:5d:39:55": {
    "version": "OF_13",
    "port_desc": [
      {
        "port_number": "local",
        "hardware_address": "08:00:27:5d:39:55",
        "name": "flips",
        "config": [
          "PORT_DOWN"
        ],
        "state": [
          "LINK_DOWN"
        ],
        "current_features": [],
        "advertised_features": [],
        "supported_features": [],
        "peer_features": [],
        "curr_speed": "0",
        "max_speed": "0"
      },
      {
        "port_number": "1",
        "hardware_address": "08:00:27:5d:39:55",
        "name": "eth1",
        "config": [],
        "state": [],
        "current_features": [
          "PF_1GB_FD",
          "PF_COPPER",
          "PF_AUTONEG"
        ],
        "advertised_features": [
          "PF_10MB_HD",
          "PF_10MB_FD",
          "PF_100MB_HD",
          "PF_100MB_FD",
          "PF_1GB_FD",
          "PF_COPPER",
          "PF_AUTONEG"
        ],
        "supported_features": [
          "PF_10MB_HD",
          "PF_10MB_FD",
          "PF_100MB_HD",
          "PF_100MB_FD",
          "PF_1GB_FD",
          "PF_COPPER",
          "PF_AUTONEG"
        ],
        "peer_features": [],
        "curr_speed": "1000000",
        "max_speed": "1000000"
      },
      {
        "port_number": "2",
        "hardware_address": "08:00:27:86:14:71",
        "name": "eth2",
        "config": [],
        "state": [],
        "current_features": [
          "PF_1GB_FD",
          "PF_COPPER",
          "PF_AUTONEG"
        ],
        "advertised_features": [
          "PF_10MB_HD",
          "PF_10MB_FD",
          "PF_100MB_HD",
          "PF_100MB_FD",
          "PF_1GB_FD",
          "PF_COPPER",
          "PF_AUTONEG"
        ],
        "supported_features": [
          "PF_10MB_HD",
          "PF_10MB_FD",
          "PF_100MB_HD",
          "PF_100MB_FD",
          "PF_1GB_FD",
          "PF_COPPER",
          "PF_AUTONEG"
        ],
        "peer_features": [],
        "curr_speed": "1000000",
        "max_speed": "1000000"
      },
      {
        "port_number": "3",
        "hardware_address": "08:00:27:aa:7d:02",
        "name": "eth3",
        "config": [],
        "state": [],
        "current_features": [
          "PF_1GB_FD",
          "PF_COPPER",
          "PF_AUTONEG"
        ],
        "advertised_features": [
          "PF_10MB_HD",
          "PF_10MB_FD",
          "PF_100MB_HD",
          "PF_100MB_FD",
          "PF_1GB_FD",
          "PF_COPPER",
          "PF_AUTONEG"
        ],
        "supported_features": [
          "PF_10MB_HD",
          "PF_10MB_FD",
          "PF_100MB_HD",
          "PF_100MB_FD",
          "PF_1GB_FD",
          "PF_COPPER",
          "PF_AUTONEG"
        ],
        "peer_features": [],
        "curr_speed": "1000000",
        "max_speed": "1000000"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am using below set of code to recieve Json from Rest:

```
Map<String, SwitchAllJson> switchMap = response.getEntity(new GenericType<Map<String, SwitchAllJson>>(){});
```

Below are my Java Classes:

```
public class SwitchAllJson {
    private String version;
    private List<PortDescriptionJson> portDesc =new  ArrayList<PortDescriptionJson>();

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
    public List<PortDescriptionJson> getPortDesc() {
        return portDesc;
    }
    public void setPortDesc(List<PortDescriptionJson> portDesc) {
        this.portDesc = portDesc;
    }

}


public class PortDescriptionJson {

      private String portNumber;
      private String hardwareAddress;
      private String name;
      private List<String> config;
      private List<String> state;
      private List<String> currentFeatures;
      private List<String> advertisedFeatures;
      private List<String> supportedFeatures;
      private List<String> peerFeatures;
      private String currSpeed;
      private String maxSpeed;

    public String getHardwareAddress(){
         return this.hardwareAddress;
    }

    public String getPortNumber(){
         return this.portNumber;
    }

    public void setHardwareAddress(String hardwareAddress){
         this.hardwareAddress=hardwareAddress;
    }

    public void setPortNumber(String portNumber){
         this.portNumber=portNumber;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    public void setConfig(List<String> config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public List<String> getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(List<String> state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public List<String> getCurrentFeatures() {
        return currentFeatures;
    }

    public void setCurrentFeatures(List<String> currentFeatures) {
        this.currentFeatures = currentFeatures;
    }

    public List<String> getAdvertisedFeatures() {
        return advertisedFeatures;
    }

    public void setAdvertisedFeatures(List<String> advertisedFeatures) {
        this.advertisedFeatures = advertisedFeatures;
    }

    public List<String> getSupportedFeatures() {
        return supportedFeatures;
    }

    public void setSupportedFeatures(List<String> supportedFeatures) {
        this.supportedFeatures = supportedFeatures;
    }

    public List<String> getPeerFeatures() {
        return peerFeatures;
    }

    public void setPeer_features(List<String> peerFeatures) {
        this.peerFeatures = peerFeatures;
    }

    public String getCurrSpeed() {
        return currSpeed;
    }

    public void setCurrSpeed(String currSpeed) {
        this.currSpeed = currSpeed;
    }

    public String getMaxSpeed() {
        return maxSpeed;
    }

    public void setMaxSpeed(String maxSpeed) {
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    }


}
```

I am able to parse `00:00:08:00:27:5d:39:55` and version but I am getting `null` in `port_desc`. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Off-topic hint: if you want to increase chances of getting proper answer, try to limit your example to minimum. Not many people are willing to debug hundreds of code lines. Read more about: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE]. Also there is high chance that while creating such minimal example you will even find cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename the properties' name to Json field names. e.g. portDesc -> port_desc

Comment: it's because you have to have the same name in the json text and java class, otherwise the deserilizer won't be able to map them correctly.

Comment: You can use http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/ to convert json to java class